# Parsing Json using jquery - not getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting following values from server

```
{"status":{"message":"success","code":200},"data":[{"sent":"test","category":"Appo","experience_time":"2014-10-07","sent_id":4501922,"categoryId":4011,"score":"Negative","feature":"emp","op":"challenges"}]}
```

I need to get the value of sent,category,experience_time,sent_id,score,feature,op etc

I have tried following so far.But not getting  any value.

```
 var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

          $.each(result, function(index, value) {

alert(value.score);

        });
```

Comment: You need to use `$.each(result.data, function(index, value) {});` since `result.data` contains the array you want to iterate over

Comment: also make sure that `data` is a string not a object before calling `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` - check your browser console to see whether there are any errors?

Comment: try this,alert(data['score']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```js
var jsonString = '{"status":{"message":"success","code":200},"data":[{"sent":"test","category":"Appo","experience_time":"2014-10-07","sent_id":4501922,"categoryId":4011,"score":"Negative","feature":"emp","op":"challenges"}]}';


var result = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);

$.each(result.data, function(index, value) {

  alert(value.score);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```